# Cannot boot Windows 7 after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed ubuntu on a seperate partition I made in windows disk management. When starting my pc, windows 7 loads automatically and after reading forums I ran boot-repair in terminal loaded from the ubuntu installation disc. After that I can only load ubuntu and loading windows 7 is no longer an option.

This is the link to my [Boot info script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11906798/)

Answer (score 0):

Run this at the command line:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

That should install GRUB with fresh config files, and it should make all well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your grub loader information.  It is missing the Windows entry in the grub menu.

Go to a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> all at the same time.  Then type in the following to update the grub menu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

when the update is completed, you should be able to reboot your system, and your grub menu should appear with Windows as the last option to boot to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AdamK You're so welcome!  =)  Make sure you do the check mark to the left of the answer.